# Round gdal_translate AAIGrid output to 4 decimal places

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, esri-ascii-raster

How can I use gdal_translate for AAIGrid so that the raster values are not more than 4 decimal places.

Comment: Starting with GDAL 1.11, another option is SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS=4 from the help http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html use -co SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS=4 if that works as advertised can you please answer your own question to attest that this parameter works.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong text, it's -co DECIMAL_PRECISION=4, from the same page. The SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS option might force exponent notation which may or may not be 100% supported by various packages.

Comment: tried both. if the number is 3.4449939727783203125 the SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS=5 produces 3.445 and DECIMAL_PRECISION=5 produces 3.44499

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by adding `-co DECIMAL_PRECISION=4` in gdal_translate command.